# Удаление многомерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память

Учебник- практикум Павловская Т. А.: Освобождение памяти массива с любым количеством измерений выполняется с помощью операции `delete []`.
т.е.:

```
int ** mas = new int * [N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) mas[i]=new int [M];
delete [] mas --- ??????????
```

или правильно все же удалять циклом

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) delete [] mas[i];
delete [] mas;
```

Comment: Во-первых у массива может быть только одно измерение, встроенной поддержки многомерных массивов в языке нет. Во-вторых память из-под массива действительно освобождается при помощи `delete []`. Другое дело, что освобождать массивы, указатели на которые хранятся в `mas` тоже надо.

Comment: Ну вот такие учебники пишут. Я сам на голову одевал, не одевается.

Answer (score 1):

Только циклом! Иначе вы получаете утечку памяти - вы удаляете только блок памяти, выделенный для указателей, но не блоки памяти, выделенные для указателей в этом первом блоке!